# Updating expiration with replace / put has no effect on local node

Tags: java, caching, infinispan, jgroups

I'm using Infinispan 6.0.2's cache and all my cache entries have an expiration date which may change during it's life time. I'm updating the infinispan lifespan with the `Cache.replace` method:

```
    manager.begin();
    Data current = cache.get(token);
    Data copy = new Data(current);
    update(copy);
    validTokens.replace(token, copy, copy.getLifespan(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    manager.commit();
```

After observing expiration didn't happen as expected I dumped the cache's internal data structure and found it's local meta data isn't updated across all cache instances in the same way. State on both caches after initial put:

```
[{
        "entry" : {
            "key" : "2c90c80f-dcfc-4ab9-b1c5-ad7f253923b3",
            "value" : {
                [...]
            },
            "metadata" : {
                "version" : {
                    "topologyId" : 2,
                    "version" : 1
                },
                "lifespan" : 86400000,
                "maxIdle" : 86400000
            },
            "created" : false,
            "lastUsed" : 1458213367042,
            "expired" : false,
            "null" : false,
            "valid" : false,
            "loaded" : false,
            "removed" : false,
            "changed" : false,
            "evicted" : true
        },
        "hash" : 718741768,
        "null" : false,
        "valid" : false,
        "loaded" : false,
        "created" : false,
        "removed" : false,
        "changed" : false,
        "evicted" : true,
        "expired" : false
    }
]
```

After replacing the entry on the node initiating the replacement:

```
[{
        "entry" : {
            "key" : "2c90c80f-dcfc-4ab9-b1c5-ad7f253923b3",
            "value" : {
                [...]
            },
            "metadata" : {
                "version" : {
                    "topologyId" : 2,
                    "version" : 2
                },
                "lifespan" : 86400000,
                "maxIdle" : 86400000
            },
            "created" : false,
            "lastUsed" : 1458213394345,
            "expired" : false,
            "null" : false,
            "valid" : false,
            "loaded" : false,
            "removed" : false,
            "changed" : false,
            "evicted" : true
        },
        "hash" : 718741768,
        "null" : false,
        "valid" : false,
        "loaded" : false,
        "created" : false,
        "removed" : false,
        "changed" : false,
        "evicted" : true,
        "expired" : false
    }
]
```

On the second cache is actually changed:

```
[{
        "entry" : {
            "key" : "2c90c80f-dcfc-4ab9-b1c5-ad7f253923b3",
            "value" : {
                [...]
            },
            "metadata" : {
                "version" : {
                    "topologyId" : 2,
                    "version" : 2
                },
                "lifespan" : 57314,
                "maxIdle" : 57314
            },
            "created" : false,
            "lastUsed" : 1458213394349,
            "expired" : false,
            "null" : false,
            "loaded" : false,
            "valid" : false,
            "changed" : false,
            "removed" : false,
            "evicted" : true
        },
        "hash" : 1057353610,
        "null" : false,
        "loaded" : false,
        "valid" : false,
        "created" : false,
        "changed" : false,
        "removed" : false,
        "evicted" : true,
        "expired" : false
    }
]
```

Expiration consequently only happens on the second cache.

Cache configuration used:

```
builder
        .clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC)
        .transaction().transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL)
        .lockingMode(LockingMode.OPTIMISTIC).locking().isolationLevel(IsolationLevel.REPEATABLE_READ)
        .writeSkewCheck(true).versioning().enable()
        .scheme(VersioningScheme.SIMPLE)
        .expiration().enableReaper().wakeUpInterval(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Could you reproduce this with latest Infinispan (8.2.0)?

Comment: Works in 8.2.0. But I'm stuck with java 6 :(

Comment: There are several things you can try doing: You can try to figure out what exactly the bug is by looking at the code, and then see if comparing with the current code you can see the change that sorted it out. Another alternative is that you try to look through our issue tracking system ([here](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=21&projectKey=ISPN)) and see if you can locate the issue. The final option is professional support.